# Distinct rows with non-null values taking precedence over nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two duplicated two rows except one column of the row has null value and another one has some value. For example

```
CarName  Owner  PreviousOwner
Honda    XXX    YYYYY
Honda    XXX    
Nissan   ZZZ    AAAA
Nissan   ZZZ    
BMW      BBB
Benz     CCC    DDD
```

OUTPUT should be

```
Honda    XXX    YYYYY
Nissan   ZZZ    AAAA
BMW      BBB
Benz     CCC    DDD
```

Can you please help  me to write a query for this.

Answer (score 1):

If we were to order the records such that the previous owner with a value came 
   on top, then all you would have to do is select the topmost row. In order to achieve that, I used the row_number() along with ordering of previous_owner. Please see below:

```
select carname, owner, previous_owner from 
(select cars.*, rowid, row_number() over (partition by carname, owner order by 
previous_owner) rid 
from cars) 
where rid <=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
select CarName, Owner, max(PreviousOwner)
from t
group by CarName, Owner
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
select t.CarName, t.Owner, r.PreviousOwner
from (select Carname, max(previousowner)
       from test 
       group by carname) r
inner join test t 
on t.carname = r.carname and t.previousowner = r.previousowner
group by t.CarName, t.Owner, r.PreviousOwner;
```